# cassandra db slow connection

Tags: java, cassandra, connection

I am trying cassandra db for the first time with Java.  I have the following code where the connection to the db (cluster.connect) takes from 2-4 seconds.

I have the database on localhost with an SSD disk. I have only one cassandra node. Any hints how to improve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cluster cluster;
        Session session;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("10.90.1.15").withPort(9042).build();
        session = cluster.connect("demo");

        long connectiontime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(connectiontime - start);

        ResultSet results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users");
        long querytime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(querytime - connectiontime);

        for (Row row : results) {
            System.out.format("%s %d\n", row.getString("firstname"), row.getInt("age"));
        }

            ResultSet results2 = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users");
            long querytime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

            System.out.println(querytime2 - querytime);

           for (Row row : results2) {
                System.out.format("%s %d\n", row.getString("firstname"), row.getInt("age"));
            }

            cluster.close();
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason you are concerned with connection time? Most C* API's just stay connected to the database.

Comment: Ok I will do that, I plan to establish the connection on application deploy and then use it during the whole application lifespan

Answer (score 3):

Remember that Cassandra connections are somewhat heavy since they are intended to be set up once and then used for a long period of time.  It wouldn't be correct usage to connect and disconnect for each small operation.

That being said, 2-4 seconds is rather long.  When I connect to a remote cluster it takes about 750 ms.

You might have a look at the cassandra log to see if it's doing something strange and waiting for a timeout on something.  You could try using "localhost" instead of the machine IP for the contact point and see if that makes any difference.  If you look at the logs you could increase the log level to TRACE and you might be able to see where it is spending all the time.

Comment: I run cassandra in a virtual machine on my laptop using virtualbox, so I am not able to use localhost, I will try to investigate the logs. Of course this is just my first try with cassandra but I was amazed that the connection is so slow.

Comment: Running in a virtual machine is probably contributing to the slowness.  I'd check that you have allocated a decent amount of RAM and multiple CPU cores for the VM settings in virtualbox.